# How to use hostname verification with Jersey 1.17 and apache connector

Tags: java, jersey-client, jersey-1.0

Currently I'm able to connect successfully over https with Jersey using the apache connector, but the hostname verification I've set does not appear to be used.

```
HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(final String hostname, final SSLSession session) {
                return false;
            }
        };
HTTPSProperties httpsProperties = new HTTPSProperties(hostnameVerifier, sslContext);
final ApacheHttpClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultApacheHttpClientConfig();
clientConfig.getProperties().put(HTTPSProperties.PROPERTY_HTTPS_PROPERTIES, httpsProperties);
final Client client = this.clientFactory.getClient(clientConfig);
```

The HTTPS settings work fine, except the hostname verification. No logging output, and breakpoints are not hit within the verify method. Wondering if I'm setting the hostname verifier incorrectly?

(side note - I realise 1.17 isn't the latest version of  jersey, but at the moment updating isn't a good option for me).

Comment: can you add your SSLContext as well?

Comment: One thing to note is that the hostname verifier is only called if the server hostname and cert info actually mismatch, so you need to test this against an endpoint that has this setup incorrectly.